# Any suggestions for a nice ASP.NET Ajax tooltip?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-ajax

I am looking for a nice tooltip control (with delay) in ASP.NET AJAX. I know there are many nice Javascript libraries out there, but since I am already using ASP.NET AJAX, I may just as well use that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An "oldie-but-goodie" that I have used many times for tooltips would be [overlib](http://www.bosrup.com/web/overlib/)  It's quite nice, VERY flexible and can be used independent of any particular AJAX platform.

Answer (score 1):

[**Telerik** seems to have the mojo](http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/tooltip/examples/default/defaultcs.aspx) in this area, but since I assume you're looking for free...

The nicest ones appear to be **jQuery plugins**, like this one:
http://rndnext.blogspot.com/2009/02/jquery-ajax-tooltip.html

There is also this **ASP.Net AJAX TooltipExtender**:
http://weblogs.asp.net/cjdevos/archive/2008/03/29/asp-net-ajax-tooltipextender.aspx

Answer (score 1):

I was able to make a pretty nice balloon popup using the PopupControlExtender from the [ASP.Net AJAX Control Toolkit](http://www.asp.net/ajax/AjaxControlToolkit/Samples/). You can specify the target control to invoke the popup, the control or div that contains the popup content, and you can also dynamically populate the content using an AJAX callback to a service method.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend:

1. Pure JavaScript with Ajax capability:
   [Menucool Tooltip](http://www.menucool.com/tooltip/javascript-tooltip)
2. ASP.NET version, with Ajax Load On Demand:
   [Menubasic Tooltip](http://www.menubasic.com/Tooltip/Ajax-tooltip-control.aspx)
3. If you don't need the Ajax feature, Menucool has a very easy-to-use CSS tooltip either.

Answer (score 0):

One option is [WZ_Tooltip](http://www.walterzorn.com).  Most tooltips are basic javascript; you should not expect to find much in the way of .NET integrated tooltips, since there is not much reason to use it rather than just using a javascript.